# What's wrong with this JPQL: 'No data type for node'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have the following Query

```
  @Query("Select cp from ChannelProgramme cp"
      + " where cp.programme.programmeId in (select programmeId from Programme programme"
      + " inner join programme.performers performer"
      + " where performer.performerId in :performerID)"
      + " AND (cp.progDate BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate)"
      + " ORDER BY cp.progDate, cp.startTime")
  List<ChannelProgramme> findScheduledPerformerProgrammes(@Param("performerID") Long performerId, @Param("fromDate") Date fromDate, @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
```

Which is throwing the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'programmeId' {originalText=programmeId}

    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:924)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4905)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.inRhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4806)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4473)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
```

I can't spot the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `select programmeId from Programme programme` must be `select Programme.programmeId from Programme Programme`

Comment: Thank you! I was staring at that until I was blue in the face!

Answer (score 1):

`programmeId`  is not an defined alias in your "select".